# What is an efficient way to rank common shared sub-arrays of multiple arrays by size and frequency?

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm, subset

I'm working on a problem around Instagram hashtags. Users often have "bundles" of hashtags that they copy and paste when they are posting images. Different bundles for different topics.

So I might have my "Things from the garden" bundle, which would be ["garden", "beautifullawns", "treesoutside", "greenlondon"] and so on. They're often twenty to thirty items long.

Sometimes they might have several of these to keep things varied.

What I want to do is by looking at past images that they have posted, to recommend a bundle of tags to use.

To do that I would have several arrays of tags that they have used previously:

```
x = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
y = ["a", "b", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
z = ["a", "c", "d", "e", "f", "h"]
...
```

I'd like to find largest common subsets of entries for these arrays.

So in this case, the largest subset would be ["a", "d", "e"] within those three. That's simple enough to achieve naively by using something like `x & y & z`.

However, I'd like to create a ranking of these subsets based on their size and frequency within all of the arrays under consideration, so that I can display the most commonly used bundles of tags:

```
[
  {bundle: ["a","d","e"], frequency: 3, size: 3},
  {bundle: ["e","f"], frequency: 2, size: 2},
  {bundle: ["a","b"], frequency: 2, size: 2},
  {bundle: ["b","d"], frequency: 2, size: 2},
  ...
]
```

Presumably, with a limitation on the minimum size of these bundles, say two items.

I'm using Elasticsearch for indexing, but I've found that attempting to do this with aggregations is challenging, so I'm pulling out the images into Ruby and then working there to create the listing.

As a first pass, I've looped over all of these arrays, then find all subsets of the other arrays, using an MD5 hash key as a unique identifier. But this limits the results. Adding further passes makes this approach quite inefficient, I suspect.

```
require 'digest'

x = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
y = ["a", "b", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
z = ["a", "c", "d", "e", "f", "h"]


def bundle_report arrays
  arrays = arrays.collect(&:sort)
  working = {}
  arrays.each do |array|
    arrays.each do |comparison|
      next if array == comparison
      subset = array & comparison
      key = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(subset.join(""))
      working[key] ||= {subset: subset, frequency: 0}
      working[key][:frequency] += 1
      working[key][:size] = subset.length
    end
  end
  working
end

puts bundle_report([x, y, z])
=> {"bb4a3fb7097e63a27a649769248433f1"=>{:subset=>["a", "b", "d", "e"], :frequency=>2, :size=>4}, "b6fdd30ed956762a88ef4f7e8dcc1cae"=>{:subset=>["a", "c", "d", "e"], :frequency=>2, :size=>4}, "ddf4a04e121344a6e7ee2acf71145a99"=>{:subset=>["a", "d", "e", "f"], :frequency=>2, :size=>4}}
```

Adding a second pass gets this to a better result:

```
def bundle_report arrays
  arrays = arrays.collect(&:sort)
  working = {}
  arrays.each do |array|
    arrays.each do |comparison|
      next if array == comparison
      subset = array & comparison
      key = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(subset.join(""))
      working[key] ||= {subset: subset, frequency: 0}
      working[key][:frequency] += 1
      working[key][:size] = subset.length 
    end
  end

  original_working = working.dup

  original_working.each do |key, item|
    original_working.each do |comparison_key, comparison|
      next if item == comparison
      subset = item[:subset] & comparison[:subset]
      key = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(subset.join(""))
      working[key] ||= {subset: subset, frequency: 0}
      working[key][:frequency] += 1
      working[key][:size] = subset.length
    end
  end
  working
end

puts bundle_report([x, y, z])
=> {"bb4a3fb7097e63a27a649769248433f1"=>{:subset=>["a", "b", "d", "e"], :frequency=>2, :size=>4}, "b6fdd30ed956762a88ef4f7e8dcc1cae"=>{:subset=>["a", "c", "d", "e"], :frequency=>2, :size=>4}, "ddf4a04e121344a6e7ee2acf71145a99"=>{:subset=>["a", "d", "e", "f"], :frequency=>2, :size=>4}, "a562cfa07c2b1213b3a5c99b756fc206"=>{:subset=>["a", "d", "e"], :frequency=>6, :size=>3}}
```

Can you suggest an efficient way to establish this ranking of large subsets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than do an intersection of every array with every other array, which might quickly get out of hand, I'd be tempted to keep a persistent index (in Elasticsearch?) of all the possible combinations seen so far, along with a count of their frequency. Then for every new set of tags, increment the frequency counts by 1 for all the sub-combinations from that tag.

Here's a quick sketch:

```
require 'digest'

def bundle_report(arrays, min_size = 2, max_size = 10)

  combination_index = {}

  arrays.each do |array|

    (min_size..[max_size,array.length].min).each do |length|

      array.combination(length).each do |combination|

        key = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(combination.join(''))

        combination_index[key] ||= {bundle: combination, frequency: 0, size: length}
        combination_index[key][:frequency] += 1

      end

    end

  end

  combination_index.to_a.sort_by {|x| [x[1][:frequency], x[1][:size]] }.reverse

end

input_arrays = [
  ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
  ["a", "b", "d", "e", "f", "g"],
  ["a", "c", "d", "e", "f", "h"]
]

bundle_report(input_arrays)[0..5].each do |x|
  puts x[1]
end
```

Which results in:

```
{:bundle=>["a", "d", "e"], :frequency=>3, :size=>3}
{:bundle=>["d", "e"], :frequency=>3, :size=>2}
{:bundle=>["a", "d"], :frequency=>3, :size=>2}
{:bundle=>["a", "e"], :frequency=>3, :size=>2}
{:bundle=>["a", "d", "e", "f"], :frequency=>2, :size=>4}
{:bundle=>["a", "b", "d", "e"], :frequency=>2, :size=>4}
```

This might not scale very well either though.

Comment: Thanks Frankie! I'm having a think through and I shall reply. Really appreciate you taking a look.